# XQuiSoft.Logging attributes

Tags: logging

I am using XQuiSoft.Logging to log errors in my application. 
In the web.config, I can set the size of the log file, path, and level. But I don't know how to set the number of backups of the log files. 
For example, I only want to keep 2 log files at the same time. When a log file reaches to the size limit, a new log file will be created. Once the new log file reaches to the size limit, the very first one should be deleted automatically and another log file should be generated.
Any inputs will be appreciated.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="XQuiSoft.Logging">
        <section name="Log"
                 type="XQuiSoft.Logging.LogConfiguration, XQuiSoft.Logging"/>
        <section name="FilterManager"
                 type="XQuiSoft.Logging.FilterConfiguration, XQuiSoft.Logging"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <add key="CurrentEnvironment" value="Build"/>
</appSettings>
<XQuiSoft.Logging>
    <Log>
        <providers>

            <add name="Build"
                 type="XQuiSoft.Logging.BufferedLogProvider, XQuiSoft.Logging"
                 TargetProviderNames="FileLogger-Build"
                 OutputInterval="2"
                 ExclusiveEnvironmentName="Build"
                 ExceptionProviderName="null"/>
            <add name="FileLogger-Build"
                 type="XQuiSoft.Logging.RollingFileLogProvider, XQuiSoft.Logging"
                 FilePath="D:\Logs\Build\log"
                 Extension=".txt"
                 MaximumFileSize="10MB"
                 ActiveRoot="false"
                 ExceptionProviderName="null"
                 ItemFormat="{Timestamp:yyyyMMdd:HHmmss}: {Level}: {Source}: {Category}: {Message}: {Details}"
                 FilterName="Verbose"/>
        </providers>
    </Log>
    <FilterManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="Verbose"
                 type="XQuiSoft.Logging.LevelFilter, XQuiSoft.Logging"
                 MaxLevel="Verbose"/>
            <add name="ErrorsAndWarnings"
                 type="XQuiSoft.Logging.LevelFilter, XQuiSoft.Logging"
                 MaxLevel="Warning"/>
        </providers>
    </FilterManager>
</XQuiSoft.Logging>
```

Comment: I found that adding attribute MaximumFileCount can limit the number of log files.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding attribute MaximumFileCount can limit the number of log files.